# Przelewy24 payment getway transaction notification not getting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, notifications, payment-gateway

I have implemented the Payment method and I had to provide **URL_STATUS** to get the payment status notification but when  trying to catch the notification on my backend and I could not catch it "https://developers.przelewy24.pl/index.php?en#section/Payment-system/Transaction-process" this is their a document to get status.

here is my code in python.

```
class PaymentVerify(APIView):
def post(self, request):

    try:
        data = request.data
        data.get
    except (KeyError, ValueError, AttributeError):
        return Response(
            "Need valid JSON dictionary.", 404)

    if data:
        print(data)
        return Response(
            {'message': 'Payment successful!'},
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response(
            {'message': 'Payment unsuccessful!'},
            status=status.HTTP_400_OK)
```

I am not able to catch anything, can you please help me to catch this error. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems with your code.

In case of any error  (except `KeyError`, `ValueError`, `AttributeError`) your `data` variable will not be set. So `if data:` part will raise another error. Move if/else part inside try/catch block unless you have a better option.

```
    ...
    try:
        data = request.data
        data.get
        if data:
            print(data)
            return Response({'message': 'Payment successful!'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({'message': 'Payment unsuccessful!'}, status=status.HTTP_400_OK)
    except (KeyError, ValueError, AttributeError):
        return Response(
            "Need valid JSON dictionary.", 404)
```

you can make those a bit better by using walrus operator (if your python version lets you so).

```
if data := some_result:
    do_something_with_data
```

The second problem is, you have just thrown away a documentation and two lines of code,

```
data = request.data
data.get
```

and asking where to set/get URL_STATUS and complaining about transaction notifications.

Please define your problem accurately and post your solution attempts too if any.